# Stress visualization for structured and unstrcutured mesh

Tags: visualization, unstructured-mesh, paraview

I put together a FEM solver to do some structural analysis. At the moment I am trying to add stress visualization feature to my code. The post-processing is done with Paraview and the results with which I am trying to verify my code are from the following problem:

The structure is two square plates welded on one edge together to form the figure shown in the images below. The structure is clamped at two points as shown by red circles and a uniformely distributed load is applied on the upper edge of the structure as shown below. 
The simulation was run once using structured mesh and second time using unstructured mesh the results using structured mesh are somehow reasonable even though not completely satisfactory but the results from unstructured mesh are absolutely off base!

At a first glimpse what could be done wrong in transition from structured mesh to unstructured mesh (from coding point of view) that results in such discrepancy?

[image: Stress visualization for an structured mesh using Paraview]

[image: Stress visualization for an unstructured mesh using Paraview]

Comment: We can't know -- it may be that you have a bug in your computation of the displacement field, or that you have a bug computing the stresses from the displacements.

Comment: I would suggest that you start with the simplest problem, i.e., a problem with uniaxial stress. I agree with Wolfgang, you don't provide enough information so we don't know why the results don't match.

Comment: @nicoguaro I suspected that the information I provided may not be sufficient, I will check the displacement field calculation to see if the problem comes from there. Thanks for the comments.